# Dynamic UIView using viewWillLayoutSubviews above prototype cells in UITableViewController drawing frame over the tableView

Tags: ios

I'm using viewWillLayoutSubviews method to redraw the frame of a UIView above a tableview based on the contents of that UIView.  I am able to redraw the UIView's frame to match the height of text, but the problem is that there's no way to do constraints from the UIView above the tableview to the tableview itself, so when the frame is redrawn, it will draw itself over the tableview, making it look like this:

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajZNo.jpg!

Comment: why dont you just set your view as the headerview of the tableview?

Comment: If I recall correctly, you have to re-set the view as the tableHeaderView after any resizing that you do.

Comment: But the tableheaderview follows the cells as they scroll.  I want that entire view to disappear if i scroll down. If there are a lot of replies, you should be able to see the full view as a tableview if they scroll down

Comment: UPDATE: I set the tableheaderview in viewdidappear and now it works, but the user can see the view update itself when it opens.  If I update the tableheaderview in viewwillappear, it doesn't work.  I guess willLayoutSubviews is called before viewWillAppear?